# Calling a macro inside another macro in Twig

Tags: twig

How `button_primary` macro can call `button` macro in Twig engine? I've tried 
 this solution, but it doesn't work, it says that *the function "button" does not exist*:

```
{% macro button(label, type, size) %}
    {% set type = type|default('default') %}
    {% set size = size|default('large') %}
    {% set cls = ['btn'] %}

    <a href="#" class="{{ cls|join(' ') }}">{{ label }}</a>
{% endmacro %}

{% macro button_primary(label, size) %}
    {{ button(label, 'primary', size) }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

EDIT: As per cr4zydeejay's answer Feb 7th 2021 the answer was updated to reflect the correct way in Twig 3.x

### Twig 3.x

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/macro.html

> When macro usages and definitions are in the same template, you don't
> need to import the macros as they are automatically available under
> the special _self variable:

```html
    <p>{{ _self.input('password', '', 'password') }}</p>

    {% macro input(name, value, type = "text", size = 20) %}
        <input type="{{ type }}" name="{{ name }}" value="{{ value|e }}" size="{{ size }}"/>
    {% endmacro %}
```

### Twig 2.x

Unfortunatly Gremo's answer works, but is not the right way to do it.

> When you define a macro in the template where you are going to use it, you might be tempted to call the macro directly via _self.input() instead of importing it; even if seems to work, this is just a side-effect of the current implementation and it won't work anymore in Twig 2.x.

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html

**Correct way:**

```html
    {% macro input(name, value, type, size) %}
        <input type="{{ type|default('text') }}" name="{{ name }}" value="{{ value|e }}" size="{{ size|default(20) }}" />
    {% endmacro %}
    
    {% macro wrapped_input(name, value, type, size) %}
        {% import _self as forms %}
    
        <div class="field">
            {{ forms.input(name, value, type, size) }}
        </div>
    {% endmacro %}
```

Comment: Good point. I can't remember that notice at the time of the question. Thanks anyways...

Comment: Thank you for "_self". This was key in my being able to render a custom menu in a paragraph template.

Answer (score 6):

Answer to myself: it's a quite new feature added, see [this link](https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/commit/a8031fc96a8dbb88c223c7046cd4ffdd385c770b). Anyway the solution is using `_self`:

```
{% macro button_primary(label, size) %}
    {{ _self.button(label, 'primary', size) }}
{% endmacro %}
```

Answer (score 1):

Gremo's answer is correct way to do this in Twig 3.x.

https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/tags/macro.html

> When macro usages and definitions are in the same template, you don’t
> need to import the macros as they are automatically available under
> the special _self variable.